# how do I figure out which 4h bar each 1h bar belongs to

Tags: pine-script

Is there an easy way to find out which 1h bar is the last 1h bar in a 4h bar?

I'm creating a trend indicator that uses the values from the 4h bar, but I place it on the 1h chart. So I only want to do calcs when I have completed the last 1h bar of the current 4h bar.

I use the request.security function to get the 4h bar data on the 1h chart.  But the bar_index function works differently on historical and live or replay bars.  On historical bars, the first 3 1h bars still have the bar_index of the previous 4h bar.  Only the 4th 1h bar has the current 4h bar_index.  See #1 and #2 on the image below.

But when I use a live chart or replay each 1h bar has the bar_index of the currently forming 4h bar. See #3 on the image below.

I tried to create a seq count so I could count down the 1h bars and know which the last 1h bar was for the currently forming 4h bar.  Works great on historical data, but not on a live chart since the bar_index calculation changes between historical and live bars.

Any other way to find the "Last" 1h bar in a 4h bar?

Or some way to get pinescript to assign bar_index the same way on historical and live bars?

any help is appreciated
thanks

Example of bar_index on historical and live/replay

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, you're correct.

To get the previous data src I use security

Example:

```
prev_close = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", close[1], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)

prev_2_close = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", close[2], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)

prev_3_close = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", close[3], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

...

Probably not the cleanest solution but it works

Comment: barmerge.lookahead_on worked perfect.  I'm not trying to "predict" price data, just want to know which longer timeframe bar I am on so I only process when the longer timeframe bar closes.  thanks for the help